# How to search as subsequence

Tags: sqlite, substring, sql-like

I would like to search through a database table and return any string that is a subsequence of another string.

When I want to search for a string that is equal to another string, I use the following:

```
SELECT kmer from data where kmer="ATCG"
```

Assuming kmer = "ATCG", a match will be made. But what if I wanted to search as a subsequence? Something like the following:

```
SELECT kmer from data where kmer in "XXATCGXX"
```

But obviously, this syntax is incorrect. These strings are static and I am not able to use wildcards with the LIKE syntax.

To be clear, any of the following values should return a match:

```
X
XX
XAT
XATC
ATC
TC
GX
CGXX
A
T
C
G
```

Just to name a few examples. These are all subsequences of "XXATCGXX" so can I use wildcats to cover all of these possibilities?

Comment: Why can't you use `LIKE` ?  Try `WHERE kmer LIKE '%ATCG%'`

Comment: What confuses me about this subject is how am I supposed to know in advance where to put the wild cards? Your example would work in this one case, but what if my string were "XXAT"? In that case a match would not be made even though it is a  subsequence of "XXATCGXX".  Or am I misunderstanding the concept of the wild card?

Comment: The `%` wildcard matches zero or more characters, so I believe the answer is yes.

Comment: Unfortunately I still do not quite understand. Would the absence of a "CG" cause a non match? Please see my edits as I provide more clarification.

Comment: So you are saying `kmer` should be a substring of your parameter? Switch the order: `WHERE "XXATCGXX" LIKE "%" || kmer || "%"`

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am referring to. I'm not near a computer now so I can't test it, but the logic seems right.

Comment: Tried this out and it worked. Thank you for your help. I tried doing this but was not familiar with the "||" syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE is typically used with a column value on the left, but as mentioned by Colonel Thirty Two, you can just reverse the comparison:

```
SELECT kmer FROM data WHERE 'XXATCGXX' LIKE '%' || kmer || '%';
```